# how to avoid a CSV file to change some rows to date format while using the text-to-column function?

Tags: excel

I have CSV file that has some data points separated with dot. While using the tex-to-column function, it changes some of the rows to date format.

I have tried to change the original column format to text but it's keep happening.
Any idea on how to avoid this?

I'm using Excel for Mac 16.50 version

Comment: ¿Can you post or upload somewhere the CSV file for testing? But probably when using text to columns you can select that column and choose text format, instead of standard

Comment: hey! I have already tried changing the column format / column formats to text. Still the same problem

Comment: As I said, without data example, or CSV file (it can be fake data, but same format) this is a shot in the dark...

Comment: Exactly when are you "changing the column format to text"?  In the Import Wizard?  Or on the worksheet?  If the latter, it won't do what you expect.

Comment: Exactly, I mean in the text to columns wizard, last step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically by changing the language preferences of my mac from German to US the comma separation changed to semicolon that solved the problem. It's a hacky way of getting rid of an annoying problem but it worked.